# адрес узла стека

Tags: c++, стек

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class List 
{
public:
    List();
    class Node {
    public:
        Node* pNext;
        int data;
        Node(int data, Node* pNext = nullptr) {
            this->data = data;
            this->pNext = pNext;
        }
    };
    int Size;
    Node *Top;
    void push_back(int data);
    void lout(List&lst);
    void lin(List &lst);
    void firstTask(List& lst1, List& lst2);
};

List::List() {
    Size = 0;
    Top = nullptr;
}

void List::push_back(int data) {
    if (Top == nullptr) {
        Top = new Node(data);
    }
    else {
        Node* current = this->Top;
        while (current->pNext != nullptr) {
            current = current->pNext;
        }
        current->pNext = new Node(data);
    }
    Size++;
}
void List::lout(List&lst) {
    cout << "Your list:" << endl;
    Node* current = Top;
    for (int i=0;i<Size;i++)  {
        cout << current->data << " ";
        current = current->pNext;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
void List::lin(List&lst) {
    cout << "How many time you want to fill in elements of list? Do not enter not integer data type!" << endl;
    int answer;
    cin >> answer;
    for (int i = 0; i < answer; i++) {
        int input;
        cin >> input;
        lst.push_back(input);
    }
}

void List::firstTask(List&lst1,List&lst2) {
    List tmp;
}

int main() {
    List lst1;
    lst1.lin(lst1);    
    lst1.lout(lst1);
    List lst2;
    lst2.lin(lst2);
    lst2.lout(lst2);
    lst2.firstTask(lst1,lst2);
}
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы Тор в методе firstTask указывал на крайний элемент списка, а не на первый?

Answer (score 1):

Не говоря о других недостатках:

Плохо, что каждый раз, добавляя в конец, объект начинает искать этот конец, перебирая свои элементы от начала до конца. А значит для n элементов, количество перебора этих элементов будет считаться математической прогрессией. Лучше, когда класс просто знает место своего последнего элемента. Поэтому, помимо Node* Top храните и  Node* end. Тогда будете иметь:

```
class List
{
public:
    //...
    int Size;
    Node* Top;
    Node* end;        
    //...

};

List::List() {
    Size = 0;
    Top = end = nullptr;    
}

void List::push_back(int data) {
    if (Top == nullptr) {
        Top = new Node(data);
        end = Top;
    }
    else {
        Node* current = end;
        end = new Node(data);
        current->pNext = end;
    }
    Size++;
}
```

Но еще нужно написать как добавить в начало, чтобы могли реализовать написание не только описанной вами функции, но и для многих других задач:

```
void List::push_front(const int data)
{
    if (Top == nullptr) {
        Top = new Node(data);
        end = Top;
    }
    else {
        Node* curr = Top;
        Top = new Node(data);
        Top->pNext = curr;
    }
}
```

Теперь можете написать вашу функцию:

```
void firstTask(List& lst1, List& lst2) {
    List tmp;
    List::Node* curr = lst1.Top;
    while (curr) {
        tmp.push_front(curr->data);
        curr = curr->pNext;
    }
    //теперь записать из lst2 в lst1 и из tmp в lst2
    //это лучше сделать в конструкторе копирования и в операторе присваивания
}
```

Но это все не будет ничего стоить, если вы не написали деструктор класса, и каждый раз будет иметь место утечка памяти. А еще нужно написать конструктор копирования и оператор присваивания. Тогда вы можете просто присвоить один список другому или инициализировать список другим списком, и пользоваться классом станет легче и безопасней  с точки зрения  не допущения логических ошибок.

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо. Насчет добавления в начало - это стек. Добавлять, если я конечно ничего не путаю, можно(нужно) только в конец

Comment: при push_front выводится пустая строка в консоль